# Enabling AJAX in Views breaks Form API AJAX button (Drupal 8)

Tags: views, 8, forms, ajax

On a product node there is form with a button "add to cart" that is implemented with form API (ajax):

```
$form['add_to_cart'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Add to cart'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'Drupal\custom_cart\Form\AddToCartForm::addProductToCart',
    'event' => 'click',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'wrapper' => '#custom-cart', 
    'progress' => array(
      'type' => 'throbber',
    ),
  )
);

...

public function addProductToCart(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
if ($parent_node_id = $form_state->getStorage()['parent_node_id']) {
  if ($product_node = Node::load($parent_node_id)) {
    $pid = $product_node->get('field_product_bid')->value;
    $price = $product_node->get('field_product_price')->value;
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    Cart::addLineItem($pid, $form_state->getValue('amount'), $price);
    $cart = Cart::getThemedCart();
    $elem = ['#markup' =>  $cart];
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('.cart-nav', $renderer->render($elem)));
    return $response;
  }
 }
}
```

This works as expected.

For a product overview page we render out product nodes with a view (node teasers) and the view includes some exposed filters. 
If the view is ajax enabled the ajax callback from the "add to cart" button (breaks) and returns a 404 error:

Request URL:http://foobar.lo/views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found

Does somebody know how to fix this (core patches anywhere?) or a workaround you know?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Better you can add code of method **addProductToCart**. Maybe the issue comes with this method.

Comment: The callback returns a 404 (for the fapi ajax) so the method is not called. The issue is probably related to js attach logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in this line of [RenderElement::preRenderAjaxForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21RenderElement.php/function/RenderElement%3A%3ApreRenderAjaxForm/8.4.x):

```
$settings['url'] = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
```

When the form with the button "add to cart" is rendered inside of an ajax request of a view, then the url is set to the wrong endpoint `/views/ajax`.

A workaround would be to add a static url in the ajax setting of the form element, so that it won't be set dynamically:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::add',
    'wrapper' => $wrapper,
    'url' => Url::fromRoute('<front>'),   // set this to the route of the view page
    'options' => ['query' => \Drupal::request()->query->all() + [FormBuilderInterface::AJAX_FORM_REQUEST => TRUE]],
  ]
```

If you use the form in multiple pages you would need to adjust the code to only set the url when the form is rendered in this view.